# Why am I seeing undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass? I need some insight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, posts

I am trying to let Users post comments on Users Posts. I have this is in show.html.erb,

```
<div id="comments">
    <%= render @posts.comments %>

        <h3>Add a Comment</h3>
            <%=  render "comments/form" %>          
</div>
```

I have this in my comments_controller.rb,

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
 end
 def create 
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
    redirect_to @post
 end
 def destroy
     @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
     @posts = Post.find(params[:post_id])
     @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
     @comment.destroy

     redirect_to post_path(@post)
 end
 private
 def comment_params
   params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :text)
 end
  end
```

This is in my posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @posts = Post.all
end
def welcome
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(4).offset(1)
    @signed_in_user = session[:user_id]
end
def posts
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == nil
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
end
def new 
    @post = Post.new
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
end
def create 
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])        
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.user_id = @signed_in_user

if  @post.save 
    redirect_to dashboard_path 
else
    render 'new'
end
end
def show
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(4).offset(1)
    @signed_in_user = session[:user_id]
end
def edit
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end 

def update
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:body))
    redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
def destroy
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.user_id = @signed_in_user

    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
 end

 private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:body)
    end
    end
```

This is in my _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <br>
 <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: This is in my routes!

```
 post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)  

 POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)  

 /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) 

 /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) 

  post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)  

  PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format) 

  PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format) 

  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format) 
  posts GET    /posts(.:format) posts#index

  POST   /posts(.:format)

  new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)   posts#new
   edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)  posts#edit
      post GET    /posts/:id(.:format) posts#show
           PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format) posts#updat

           PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)  posts#updat
```

I have been looking this up for hours but can't seem to figure it out. Its driving me crazy, If I could get some insight on what it might be that'd be great! Thanks for any advice in advance, It means a lot! Also, If I need to post more code so you can see let me know! Ill make edits!

Comment: it must be `@post.comments` ?

Comment: No, This did not work.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace at the time when this fails.  I wonder why you left that out when you have rest of the files covered.

Comment: i think that post should be a nested attribute of user, can you upload both models?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.comments` on an empty / non-initialized variable, that is what the Exception is telling you. Without seeing the error stacktrace, my bet goes to that line on your `show.html.erb` where you call `render @posts.comments`.

Move `render @posts.comments` to `render @post.comments`, which should contain a `Post` object with access to it's `comments` collection, according to your controller. I'm still not sure why that `@posts` is `nil`, since you are initializing that on your controller as an `ActiveRecord::Relation` ... but anyway you still will want to access to a `Post#comments` (hence, `@post`) on that bit.